# How to remove EC2 instance from load balancer (ELB) with AWS Systems Manager Maintenance Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssm, runcommand, amazon-systems-manager

I have EC2 instances behind an ELB. In Systems Manger, I want a way to automate taking an instance off the load balancer, then run command AWS-ApplyPatchBaseline, then putting the instance back on the load balancer.

I have successfully used Maintenance Window to automate patching, I just need to add steps to remove than re-add the instance from/to the ELB.

Comment: I haven't found any guidance on this at all. You'd think this was a common use case